# IE 8 and jquery problem

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have such div:

```
<div class="box">
    <div id="myid" style="display:hidden;"> <p>some stuff here</p></div>
</div>
```

when I execute `$("myid").slideToggle("slow");` on the html above (div "myid" is hidden) , if the content of has bigger height over box, my content overflows from the bottom  of the "box" class, weirdly this doesn't happen with other browsers but IE8

How can I fix this issue so that when "myid" starts to display content, height of the .box resizes itself to fit the inner div.

CSS for my box:

```
.box {
    background:#fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:0;
    }
```

Comment: Are you specifying the height somewhere, probably making IE8 stick to this set value?

Comment: yes, I have now added the css for my box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display:hidden;` is not what you want.  Try setting `display:none;` instead.

The main problem is that you want the box to have a minimum height, right?  But it should get bigger to fit the inner div?  You basically have to avoid setting an explicit height on the box.   You could use `min-height` but it's not supported in IE.  I would use a sibling to #myid that has an explicit height to keep the box at a minimum height.  It could be 1px wide, for example, but 50px tall (min height of 50px, then).  You would need to float your inner divs.

Here's a demo that does that: http://www.jsfiddle.net/ZKkB3/

The main limitation is that you've got that little bit of spacing on the left.  You could fix that with negative margins, I'd imagine.